# Handling different event types in Kinesis Streams

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Coming from an AMQP background, if I have an app that creates widgets, I'll create routing keys for my events such as `widget.created` and `widget.updated`. Then I can have queues bind to the events they need. So if I want to do something when a widget is created, I'll bind to `widget.created`.

Is there an equivalent to this when using Kinesis streams? I can see two possible ways (either using a separate stream for each event type or running a Lambda function that looks at each event and decides what actions to perform) but wondering if I've missed something.

Comment: How much traffic are you pushing through? If you don't have multiple consumers for each stream event, consider using SQS instead (more like a simple queue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided the SNS + SQS combination was a better like for like replacement for AMQP than Kinesis. Each service publishes to its own SNS topic, then I use an SQS queue per consumer so each message can be consumed by different Lambda functions.

Kinesis is great for pushing lots of data through to a few consumers (max 5 per stream), but I didn't want that limitation to affect me in the future.